# is there a way to set an extra metadata on model declaration into schema.prisma file

Tags: nestjs, prisma

Hi I'm newbie on prisma and nestjs, and I'm writing a backend application with nestjs and mysql, so using prisma as database connector, and i have a new requirement to define if a table is a core or non core table, so i would to know if there is a way to set a metadata inside model declaration in schema prisma file, something like this:

```
model role_mapping {
  id      String  @id @default(uuid()) @db.VarChar(50)
  roleId  String? @map("role_id") @db.VarChar(50)
  userId String? @map("user_id") @db.VarChar(50)
  role    role?   @relation(fields: [roleId], references: [id])
  user    user?   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Restrict, onUpdate: Restrict, map: "role_mapping_ibfk_1")

  @@unique([roleId, userId], map: "role_id_user_id")
  @@index([userId], map: "principal_id")
  @@index([roleId], map: "role_id")
  @@metadata (coreTable: true, someOtherMetaData: ...) <<--- like this
}
```

And how can i get it, on nestjs code?

Comment: This isn't supported by Prisma. Couldn't you store this information elsewhere though? Perhaps in a separate database table or some kind of configuration file?

Comment: ohh oki thx @TasinIshmam , yep thats the way that i'm working on, i wanted to know if prisma supported it,